# How to identify SCOUT DICOM images?

Tags: dicom

I have a set of DICOM images. From them, I want to separate/identify SCOUT images. Can you suggest an easy way to identify SCOUT between a set of DICOM files?

Answer (score 2):

Please check the 3rd value of the Image Type element (0008, 0008). This optional value 3 is used for Image IOD specific specialization. As for example, CT Image uses string "LOCALIZER" for scout image.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on *LEADTOOLS Support's* very helpful answer, this can be easily performed in Python using the `pydicom` library:

```
def is_scout(fn: str) -> bool:
    """ Identify scouts/scanograms """
    filedata = pydicom.dcmread(fn, stop_before_pixels=True, force=True)
    # (0008,0008) = Image Type
    return 'LOCALIZER' in filedata.get((0x8, 0x8), list())
```